# Monodroid viewpager out of memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I'm trying to narrow down a memory issue and have created a ViewPager with two tabs, each tab containing 5000 buttons created programmatically.  There are no static references, so I'm confused as to why the buttons don't get cleared up.

After the second button press I get an OutOfMemory error and MAT tells me I have 19,416 references to "android.widget.Button" of which the class_references tab tells me 19,416 of those are java.lang.ref.WeakReference.  I would only expect to have about 10,000 though as I call GC.Collect() before launching the activity containing the ViewPager.

I've uploaded the [converted hprof file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/m4gg0h).

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
        button.Click += delegate {
            GC.Collect();

            StartActivity(typeof(MyPagerActivity));
        };
```

MyPagerActivity:

```
public class MyPagerActivity : Activity
{
    private MyPagerAdapter m_pageradapter;
    private ViewPager m_viewpager;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (null); // Always recreate everything (parameter is null)

        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.tabactivity);

        InitialiseTabs();
    }

    void InitTab (Fragment frag, string sTitle)
    {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        m_pageradapter.AddFragment(frag);
        tab.SetText (sTitle);
        tab.TabSelected += HandleTabSelected;
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }

    void InitialiseTabs()
    {
        m_pageradapter = new MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager);
        View v = FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        m_viewpager = v.JavaCast<ViewPager>();

        InitTab(new FragLotsOfButtons (), "Buttons 1");
        InitTab(new FragLotsOfButtons (), "Buttons 2");

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        m_viewpager.PageSelected += HandlePageSwipe;
        m_viewpager.Adapter = m_pageradapter;
    }

    void HandlePageSwipe (object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActionBar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(e.Position);
    }

    void HandleTabSelected (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
    {
        m_viewpager.CurrentItem = ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex;
    }
}
```

tabactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyPagerAdapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private List<Fragment> m_frags;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragman) : base(fragman)
    {
        m_frags = new List<Fragment>();
    }

    public void AddFragment(Fragment frag)
    {
        m_frags.Add(frag);
    }

    public override int GetItemPosition (Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return FragmentStatePagerAdapter.PositionNone;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    public override Fragment GetItem (int p0)
    {
        return m_frags[p0];
    }
    #endregion
    #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter
    public override int Count {
        get {
            return m_frags.Count;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

FragLotsOfButtons:

```
public class FragLotsOfButtons : Fragment
{
    private LinearLayout m_linearlayout = null;

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        m_linearlayout = new LinearLayout (Activity);
        m_linearlayout.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WindowManagerLayoutParams.FillParent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.FillParent);
        m_linearlayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        AddButtons ();

        return m_linearlayout;
    }

    private void AddButtons ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout (Activity);
            ll.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
            ll.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            Button testview = new Button (Activity);
            testview.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
            testview.Text = "A" + i.ToString ();
            ll.AddView (testview);
            testview = new Button (Activity);
            testview.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
            testview.Text = "B" + i.ToString ();
            ll.AddView (testview);
            m_linearlayout.AddView (ll);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few solutions already on StackOverflow with no joy so far.

**EDIT:**

Exception info added:

```
Instance    {Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError' was thrown.
    at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00023] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:368
        at Android.Views.ViewGroup.AddView (Android.Views.View) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.Views.ViewGroup.cs:1357
            at PagerAdapterTest.FragLotsOfButtons.AddButtons () [0x000a5] in c:\Users\David.Wright\Documents\Projects\PagerAdapterTest\PagerAdapterTest\FragLotsOfButtons.cs:44
            at PagerAdapterTest.FragLotsOfButtons.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00032] in c:\Users\David.Wright\Documents\Projects\PagerAdapterTest\PagerAdapterTest\FragLotsOfButtons.cs:25
            at Android.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00022] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.App.Fragment.cs:990
            at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.f5d8ab18-1268-411a-908a-67c8e30f2dce (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0x0005f>

            --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3735)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3543)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3488)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3464)
            at pageradaptertest.FragLotsOfButtons.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
            at pageradaptertest.FragLotsOfButtons.onCreateView(FragLotsOfButtons.java:28)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:437)
            at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5109)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15524)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4604)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
}   Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

LogCat says:

```
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 64.406MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.822MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.888MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.888MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8800-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.888MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Out of memory on a 8800-byte allocation.
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.889MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.904MB to 64.000MB
[dalvikvm-heap] Clamp target GC heap from 65.904MB to 64.000MB
```

Comment: In which class you are geting OutOfMemory..post your logcat..

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have 10k `Buttons`, but you are also instantiating `LayoutParameters` and assigning Text to the `Buttons`, but you also encapsulate all that in `LinearLayouts`. All of that which are `Java.Lang.Objects` which makes GREF references.

I don't see anywhere, where you actually get rid of your `Fragment` instances, which are probably being held by your `Adapter`, until it deems that you do not need it anymore. So simply calling `GC.Collect()` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I don't understand why it doesn't all go out of scope when MyPagerActivity closes?  Then when I click the button from MainActivity and it calls GC.Collect() shouldn't it clear up all of the previous instance of MyPagerActivity?